# Custom Windows right-click command doesn't execute batch file as expected

Tags: windows, windows-xp, batch, windows-registry, context-menu

I'm trying to create a custom right-click command which will move a file to a folder. I have a batch file called `C:MyMove.bat` with the following code:

```
@echo off
cls
move %1 "C:/My folder/"
```

I create a new registry key with my command name at:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CustomMove\command
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MyScript1\command
```

The value of the command registry key is:

`"C:\MyMove.bat" "%1"`

The new item does appear in the right-click menu, but when I click on an object and then click on my CustomMove command it attempts to open the file instead of executing the batch file.

Note that when I run the script from the command prompt it works fine, i.e. when I run `C:MyMove.bat "<file_path>"` it does move correctly the file to `"C:/My folder/"`

Comment: What happens when you use MyMove.bat via the SendTo folder? Place a shortcut of MyMove.bat to the user's SendTo folder (shell:sendto). Right-click on a file, click SendTo, and select the Batch file shortcut. What happens now?

Comment: Placing files in the root folder of C requires administrator permission and is a BAD idea.

Comment: @harrymc what is the best location to put my bat for this purpose? In the "My Documents" folder?

Comment: @w32sh in that case it works fine!

Comment: Place it in any subfolder of the root. There are no "best" locations.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Reg Keys with your command to move your folder and use it with the right mouse button without using a bath file.

Just run as administrator to add registry entries.

```bat
:: add command :: 
Reg Add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CustomMove\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe\" /c >con: move /y \"%L\" \"C:\\Your\\Destination\\Folder\\"" /F

:: add icon ::
Reg Add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CustomMove" /t REG_SZ /v "Icon" /d "C:\\Windows\\System32\\shell32.dll,77" /f
```

Comment: SWEET! Was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reg file that adds both "Copy to folder" and "Move to folder" to your context menu.  Works when you right click a file or a folder.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; add both copy to folder and move to folder to context menu
; displays when you right-click a file or a folder

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}]

;add move to folder to context menu

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}]